# UITextField secure/visible with internationalization

Tags: ios, internationalization, passwords

I have a UITextField which is generally set to secureTextEntry = YES. There is an 'eye' icon to reveal the password which, in order to display the text, changes the textfield to secureTextEntry = NO. When the UITextField has UIKeyboardType.Default and the textfield has secureTextEntry = YES then only letters, numbers and punctuation are allowed (for the current system keyboard). When secureTextEntry = NO the standard emoji keyboard button is added to the keyboard. We obviously don't want emojis being allowed to be entered into the password textfield.

We have a temporary solution of changing the KeyboardType to UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable which limits the available options to English letters, numbers and punctuation (the same set as is displayed when secureTextEntry = YES for English keyboards) however in the future we are expecting to need to support full internationalisation and so will want to support other character sets. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: *"We obviously don't want emojis being allowed to be entered into the password textfield"* - why not? You should support any character a user can type.

Comment: Just had this discussion with the team actually. Considering how well people remember alphanumeric passwords and the skill level of our end users we're expecting more pain than it would be worth to support this. Besides the fact that iOS doesn't support secure text entry with emojis...